# How to build maven java based project in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have to import a project with Maven2. So far i installed eclipse gallelio then installed the software eclipse IAM and apache maven.

Then i create an new maven2 project with quickstart maven architecture. After that i import my java project into this maven architecture folder.

Now i don't know how to run this project as a maven architecture. I have to create a jar of my source

Please help me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want / need to create a source jar, there's no need to use an IDE at all.

Just execute `mvn source:jar` on the command line. The resulting JAR will be in the target folder.

Apart from that: I don't know IAM, but the preferred way to integrate Eclipse with Maven is [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) (formerly m2eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Maven Source plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/plugin-info.html) to tell Maven to create a source jar on every packaging.

Comment: How to do that. I started yesterday

Answer (score 0):

There are some articles on IAM previously called [q4e](http://code.google.com/p/q4e/w/list)

If you are not specifically intrested in IAM , you may have a look at [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) which is much evolved than IAM.

Alternatively you can install [spring tool suite](http://www.springsource.com/downloads/sts) which comes bundled with maven plugin

Answer (score 0):

I've abandoned Eclipse plugins for Maven altogether; they always give me pain.

Normally I just create an M2_REPO variable (in build path configuration) which points to the local Maven repository and run 'mvn eclipse:eclipse' on the command line. Then after refreshing you see the Maven-generated .project and .classpath and you can run your application in Eclipse.

Comment: *I've abandoned Eclipse plugins for Maven altogether; they always give me pain.* m2eclipse has been very stable for at least two years now. the maven eclipse plugin on the other hand is discontinued (the last version is more than a year old) and should not be used anymore